# Can someone please tell me why this Javascript print order summary function is not running?

Tags: javascript, html, web

This is a simple 4-step ice-cream ordering process. I expect it to print an order summary when finishing the fourth step, but it doesn't seem to work. When I do console.log to all the order summary functions, they weren't running. I wonder which step did I do wrong?

What I'm trying to do is to get the value of the users' choice in each step, and put them together in a strong to become the order summary text.

```js
var order = document.getElementById('order');

var orderSummary = document.getElementById('order-summary');

var flavorOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('flavor');

function chooseFlavor() {
  console.log("flavor is running");
  var flavorChosen;
  if (flavorOptions[0].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[0].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[1].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[1].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[2].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[2].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[3].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[3].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[4].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[4].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[5].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[5].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[6].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[6].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[7].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[7].value;
  } else if (flavorOptions[8].checked == true) {
    flavorChosen = flavorOptions[8].value;
  }
}

var sauceOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('sauce');

function chooseSauce() {
  console.log("sauce is running");
  var sauceChosen;
  if (sauceOptions[0].checked == true) {
    sauceChosen = sauceOptions[0].value;
  } else if (sauceOptions[1].checked == true) {
    sauceChosen = sauceOptions[1].value;
  } else if (sauceOptions[2].checked == true) {
    sauceChosen = sauceOptions[2].value;
  } else if (sauceOptions[3].checked == true) {
    sauceChosen = sauceOptions[3].value;
  }
}

var sprinklesOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('sprinkles');

function chooseSprinkles() {
  console.log("sprinkles is running");
  var sprinklesChosen;
  if (sprinklesOptions[0].checked == true) {
    sprinklesChosen = sprinklesOptions[0].value;
  } else if (sprinklesOptions[1].checked == true) {
    sprinklesChosen = sprinklesOptions[1].value;
  } else if (sprinklesOptions[2].checked == true) {
    sprinklesChosen = sprinklesOptions[2].value;
  } else if (sprinklesOptions[3].checked == true) {
    sprinklesChosen = sprinklesOptions[3].value;
  }
}

var fruitsOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('fruits');

function chooseFruits() {
  console.log("fruits is running");
  var fruitsChosen;
  if (fruitsOptions[0].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[0].value;
  } else if (fruitsOptions[1].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[1].value;
  } else if (fruitsOptions[2].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[2].value;
  } else if (fruitsOptions[3].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[3].value;
  } else if (fruitsOptions[4].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[4].value;
  } else if (fruitsOptions[5].checked == true) {
    fruitsChosen = fruitsOptions[5].value;
  }
}


order.addEventListener('click', printOrder);

function printOrder() {
  console.log('order summary');
  var orderText = 'You got a ' + flavorChosen + 'icecream with' + sauceChosen + ' ' + sprinklesChosen + 'and ' + fruitsChosen + '.'
  var orderP = document.createElement('p');
  orderP.innerHTML = orderText;
  orderSummary.appendChild(orderP);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="options item">
      <h1 class="steps">Step 1</h1>
      <div class="question">What color are you wearing?</div>

      <div class="first-set-options">
        <button name="flavor" class="options-button flavor" value="strawberryflavor" data-text-swap="Pink" data-text-original="Strawberry">Pink</button>
        <button name="flavor" class="options-button" value="chocolateflavor" data-text-swap="Brown" data-text-original="Chocolate">Brown</button>
        <button name="flavor" class="options-button" value="vanillaflavor" data-text-swap="White" data-text-original="Vanilla">White</button>
        <button name="flavor" class="options-button" value="cookiencreamflavor" data-text-swap="B&W" data-text-original="CookieNCream">B&W</button>
      </div>
      <div class="second-set-options">
        <button name="flavor" class="options-button" value="raspberryflavor" data-text-swap="Red" data-text-original="Raspberry">Red</button>
        <button name="flavor" class="options-button" value="mintchipsflavor" data-text-swap="Green" data-text-original="Mint Chips">Green</button>
        <button name="flavor" class="options-button" value="peanutbutterflavor" data-text-swap="Yellow" data-text-original="Peanut Butter">Yellow</button>
        <button name="flavor" class="options-button" value="coffeeflavor" data-text-swap="Black" data-text-original="Coffee">Black</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="options item">
      <h1 class="steps">Step 2</h1>
      <div class="question">Whom do you want to have ice cream with right now?</div>

      <div class="first-set-options">
        <button name="sauce" class="options-button sauce" value="marshmellowsauce" data-text-swap="Marshmellow Man" data-text-original="Marshmellow Sauce">Marshmellow Man</button>
        <button name="sauce" class="options-button" value="peanutbuttersauce" data-text-swap="Mr.Peanut Butter" data-text-original="Peanut Butter Sauce">MR. Peanut Butter</button>
      </div>
      <div class="second-set-options">
        <button name="sauce" class="options-button" value="hotfudgesauce" data-text-swap="Willy Wonka" data-text-original="Hot Fudge Sauce">Willy Wonka</button>
        <button name="sauce" class="options-button" value="nosauce" data-text-swap="Alone" data-text-original="No Sauce">Alone</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="options item">
      <h1 class="steps">Step 3</h1>
      <div class="question">What's the weather like right now?</div>

      <div class="first-set-options">
        <button name="sprinkles" class="options-button sprinkles" value="yogurtchips" data-text-swap="Snow" data-text-original="Yogurt Chips">Snow</button>
        <button name="sprinkles" class="options-button" value="chocolatechips" data-text-swap="Rainy" data-text-original="Chocolate Chips">Rainy</button>
      </div>
      <div class="second-set-options">
        <button name="sprinkles" class="options-button" value="mm" data-text-swap="Sunny" data-text-original="M&M">Sunny</button>
        <button name="sprinkles" class="options-button" value="coconutchips" data-text-swap="Cloudy" data-text-original="Coconut Chips">Cloudy</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="options item">
      <h1 class="steps">Step 4</h1>
      <div class="question">How are you feeling right now?</div>


      <div class="first-set-options">
        <button id="order" name="fruits" class="options-button fruits" value="mango" data-text-swap="Angry" data-text-original="Mango">Angry</button>
        <button id="order" name="fruits" class="options-button" value="pineapple" data-text-swap="Jealous" data-text-original="Pineapple">Jealous</button>
        <button id="order" name="fruits" class="options-button" value="raspberry" data-text-swap="Upset" data-text-original="Raspberry">Upset</button>
        <button id="order" name="fruits" class="options-button" value="blueberry" data-text-swap="Sad" data-text-original="Blueberry">Sad</button>
      </div>
      <div class="second-set-options">
        <button id="order" name="fruits" class="options-button" value="strawberry" data-text-swap="Fantastic" data-text-original="Strawberry">Fantastic</button>
        <button id="order" name="fruits" class="options-button" value="healthbar">Energetic</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item map-text">Get your "ice-cream of the day" at the nearest J. P. Licks store!
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="icecream_image">

    <div id="order-summary"></div>

    <img class="step1_bowl" src="images/step1_bowl.svg">
    <img class="step1_flavor" value="chocolateflavor" src="images/step1_chocolate.svg">
    <img class="step1_flavor" value="coffeeflavor" src="images/step1_coffee.svg">
    <img class="step1_flavor" value="cookiencreamflavor" src="images/step1_cookiencream.svg">
    <img class="step1_flavor" value="maplewalnutflavor" src="images/step1_maplewalnut.svg">
    <img class="step1_flavor" value="mintchipsflavor" src="images/step1_mintchips.svg">
    <img class="step1_flavor" value="peanutbutterflavor" src="images/step1_peanutbutter.svg">
    <img class="step1_flavor" value="raspberryflavor" src="images/step1_respberry.svg">
    <img class="step1_flavor" value="strawberryflavor" src="images/step1_strawberry.svg">
    <img class="step1_flavor" value="vanillaflavor" src="images/step1_vanilla.svg">
    <img class="step2_sauce" value="marshmellowsauce" src="images/step2_marshmallowsauce.svg">
    <img class="step2_sauce" value="hotfudgesauce" src="images/step2_hotfudgesauce.svg">
    <img class="step2_sauce" value="peanutbuttersauce" src="images/step2_peanutbuttersauce.svg">
    <img class="step2_sauce" value="nosauce">
    <img class="step3_sprinkles" value="mm" src="images/step3_mm.svg">
    <img class="step3_sprinkles" value="yogurtchips" src="images/step3_yogurtchips.svg">
    <img class="step3_sprinkles" value="chocolatechips" src="images/step3_chocolatechips.svg">
    <img class="step3_sprinkles" value="coconutchips" src="images/step3_coconutchips.svg">
    <img class="step4_fruits" value="mango" src="images/step4_mango.svg">
    <img class="step4_fruits" value="pineapple" src="images/step4_pinapple.svg">
    <img class="step4_fruits" value="raspberry" src="images/step4_respberry.svg">
    <img class="step4_fruits" value="blueberry" src="images/step4_blueberry.svg">
    <img class="step4_fruits" value="strawberry" src="images/step4_strawberry.svg">
    <img class="step4_fruits" value="healthbar" src="images/step4_heathbar.svg">
  </div>
```

Comment: see the console ? is there anything in red.

Comment: can you please share your images in drive or something>

Answer (score 0):

This is because your buttons contains the **same** id attribute:

```
<div class="first-set-options">
      <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="mango" data-text-swap="Angry" data-text-original="Mango">Angry</button>
      <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="pineapple" data-text-swap="Jealous" data-text-original="Pineapple">Jealous</button>
      <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="raspberry" data-text-swap="Upset" data-text-original="Raspberry">Upset</button>
      <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="blueberry" data-text-swap="Sad" data-text-original="Blueberry">Sad</button>
    </div>
    <div class="second-set-options">
      <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="strawberry" data-text-swap="Fantastic" data-text-original="Strawberry">Fantastic</button>
      <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits()"class="options-button fruits" value="healthbar">Energetic</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You cannot use the same id, id attribute is supposed to be unique.

When JavaScript encounters multiple elements of the same id, it will act in one of 2 ways:

**1)** give you the first element that matched the given id

**2)** will respond with undefined instead.

Try to distinguish between the id's and then see what happens.

If you need to get all the elements, please use `getElementByName()` or `getElementByClassName()`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="options item">
        <h1 class="steps">Step 1</h1>
        <div class="question">What color are you wearing?</div>
  
        <div class="first-set-options">
          <button id="flavour" name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor(this.value) "class="options-button fruits" value="strawberryflavor" data-text-swap="Pink" data-text-original="Strawberry">Pink</button>
          <button id="flavour" name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor(this.value) "class="ooptions-button fruits" value="chocolateflavor" data-text-swap="Brown" data-text-original="Chocolate">Brown</button>
          <button id="flavour" name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor(this.value) "class="options-button fruits" value="vanillaflavor" data-text-swap="White" data-text-original="Vanilla">White</button>
          <button id="flavour" name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor(this.value) "class="options-button fruits" value="cookiencreamflavor" data-text-swap="BW" data-text-original="CookieNCream">BW</button>
        </div>
        <div class="second-set-options">
          <button id="flavour" name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor(this.value) "class="options-button fruits" value="raspberryflavor" data-text-swap="Red" data-text-original="Raspberry">Red</button>
          <button id="flavour" name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor(this.value) " class="options-button fruits" value="mintchipsflavor" data-text-swap="Green" data-text-original="Mint Chips">Green</button>
          <button id="flavour" name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor(this.value) "class="options-button fruits" value="peanutbutterflavor" data-text-swap="Yellow" data-text-original="Peanut Butter">Yellow</button>
          <button id="flavour" name="flavor" onclick="chooseFlavor(this.value) "class="options-button fruits" value="coffeeflavor" data-text-swap="Black" data-text-original="Coffee">Black</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="options item">
        <h1 class="steps">Step 2</h1>
        <div class="question">Whom do you want to have ice cream with right now?</div>
  
        <div class="first-set-options">
          <button id="sauce" name="sauce" onclick="chooseSauce(this.value)" class="options-button sauce" value="marshmellowsauce" data-text-swap="Marshmellow Man" data-text-original="Marshmellow Sauce">Marshmellow Man</button>
          <button id="sauce" name="sauce" onclick="chooseSauce(this.value)" class="options-button sauce" value="peanutbuttersauce" data-text-swap="Mr.Peanut Butter" data-text-original="Peanut Butter Sauce">MR. Peanut Butter</button>
        </div>
        <div class="second-set-options">
          <button id="sauce" name="sauce" onclick="chooseSauce(this.value)" class="options-button sauce" value="hotfudgesauce" data-text-swap="Willy Wonka" data-text-original="Hot Fudge Sauce">Willy Wonka</button>
          <button id="sauce" name="sauce" onclick="chooseSauce(this.value)" class="options-button sauce" value="nosauce" data-text-swap="Alone" data-text-original="No Sauce">Alone</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="options item">
        <h1 class="steps">Step 3</h1>
        <div class="question">What's the weather like right now?</div>
  
        <div class="first-set-options">
          <button id="sprinkle" name="sprinkles" onclick="chooseSprinkles(this.value)"class="options-button sprinkles" value="yogurtchips" data-text-swap="Snow" data-text-original="Yogurt Chips">Snow</button>
          <button id="sprinkle" name="sprinkles" onclick="chooseSprinkles(this.value)"class="options-button sprinkles" value="chocolatechips" data-text-swap="Rainy" data-text-original="Chocolate Chips">Rainy</button>
        </div>
        <div class="second-set-options">
          <button id="sprinkle" name="sprinkles" onclick="chooseSprinkles(this.value)"class="options-button sprinkles" value="mm" data-text-swap="Sunny" data-text-original="M&M">Sunny</button>
          <button id="sprinkle" name="sprinkles" onclick="chooseSprinkles(this.value)"class="options-button sprinkles" value="coconutchips" data-text-swap="Cloudy" data-text-original="Coconut Chips">Cloudy</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="options item">
        <h1 class="steps">Step 4</h1>
        <div class="question">How are you feeling right now?</div>
  
  
        <div class="first-set-options">
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits(this.value)"class="options-button fruits" value="mango" data-text-swap="Angry" data-text-original="Mango">Angry</button>
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits(this.value)"class="options-button fruits" value="pineapple" data-text-swap="Jealous" data-text-original="Pineapple">Jealous</button>
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits(this.value)"class="options-button fruits" value="raspberry" data-text-swap="Upset" data-text-original="Raspberry">Upset</button>
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits(this.value)"class="options-button fruits" value="blueberry" data-text-swap="Sad" data-text-original="Blueberry">Sad</button>
        </div>
        <div class="second-set-options">
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits(this.value)"class="options-button fruits" value="strawberry" data-text-swap="Fantastic" data-text-original="Strawberry">Fantastic</button>
          <button id="order" name="fruits" onclick="chooseFruits(this.value)"class="options-button fruits" value="healthbar">Energetic</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="item map-text">Get your "ice-cream of the day" at the nearest J. P. Licks store!
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  
    <div class="icecream_image">
  
      <div id="order-summary"></div>
  
      
    </div>
<script>

var order = document.getElementById('order');
var orderSummary = document.getElementById('order-summary');
var flavorChosen;
function chooseFlavor(flavorC) {
  console.log("flavor is running");
  console.log("Choosen flavor is : " + flavorC);
  flavorChosen = flavorC;
  // document.getElementById("flavour").accessKey('disabled', true);
  // $("").prop();
}

var sauceChosen;
function chooseSauce(sauceC) {
  console.log("sauce is running");
  sauceChosen = sauceC;
  console.log("Choosen Sauce is : " + sauceChosen);
  
  //$("sauce").prop('disabled', true);
}

var sprinklesChosen;
function chooseSprinkles(sprinkleC) {
  console.log("sprinkles is running");
  sprinklesChosen = sprinkleC;
  console.log("Choosen Sauce is : " + sprinklesChosen);
  
  //$("sprinkle").prop('disabled', true);
}

var fruitsOptions = document.getElementsByName('fruits');
var fruitsChosen;
function chooseFruits(fruitC) {
  console.log("fruits is running");
  fruitsChosen = fruitC;
  console.log("Choosen Sauce is : " + fruitsChosen);
 
  var orderText = 'You got a ' + flavorChosen + '\t'+'icecream with' +'\t'+ sauceChosen + ' ' +'\t'+ sprinklesChosen + '\t'+'and ' +'\t'+ fruitsChosen + '.'
  var orderP = document.createElement('p');
  orderP.innerHTML = orderText;
  orderSummary.appendChild(orderP);
  //$("order").prop('disabled', true);
}


order.addEventListener('click', printOrder());

function printOrder() {
  console.log('order summary');
  
}
</script>
```

this is done by passing parameters in function.